# Does anyone know of a commonly available DPDT or DPST relay? (For use as replacement starter relay)

Tags: electrical, parts, relay

I have a car (1971 Jaguar E-Type 6 cylinder) with a bad starter relay.  The original relay is not available, and all of the specialty parts suppliers sell a generic replacement relay.

I'd like to pick up a generic replacement relay locally.

The original relay when energized connects **3 contacts** with each other (+12V, the solenoid, and a wire that makes the spark hotter).  Most relays only connect 2 contacts together, but there are plenty with more terminals that probably do exactly what I want.  Any DPDT or DPST (if such a thing exists) relay would work.  I just can't find any resource that gives a wiring diagram for these relays or a description.

The wire connections need to be 1/4" spade lugs, and I need a tab sticking out to hang it.

If anyone could provide a part number for a relay that is common enough that it would be available locally I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Doesn't meet your "pickup locally" criteria, but for others that may also be looking for parts...  I use mouser.com for my random electrical parts needs.

Answer (score 2):

Could you not just connect both the starter solenoid and the spark control wire to the single output of a standard automotive relay?